# Merge and push all git branches

Tags: git, git-svn

I've cloned an whole std-layout subversion repository with git-svn. My git config is defined as:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://firebird.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/firebird
    fetch = firebird/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = firebird/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = firebird/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:asfernandes/firebird.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

I'm pushing all branches to this github with the below bash script. I've local branches tracking the remote ones.

```
#!/bin/sh
git svn fetch
for x in `echo B1_5_Release B2_0_Release B2_1_Release B2_5_Release`; do git reset --hard; git checkout $x; git merge remotes/$x; done
git push --all
```

Isn't there a better way to do this, without checking out and merge each branch?

Even better would be if I can directly push the git-svn remotes branches without having local branches.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, if I'm reading your setup correctly:

```
git svn fetch
for x in B1_5_Release B2_0_Release B2_1_Release B2_5_Release; do
    git push origin remotes/$x:$x
done
```

This will take, for instance, `remotes/B1_5_Release` and push it to `origin/B1_5_Release`, and so on for the rest of the branches in the loop.

Since `git push` can accept multiple `<refspec>`s, you could also do it like this:

```
git svn fetch
refspecs=""
for x in B1_5_Release B2_0_Release B2_1_Release B2_5_Release; do
    refspecs="$refspecs remote/$x:$x"
done
git push origin $refspecs
```

which sacrifices a little readability for the benefit of only running one actual push command.

Answer (score 0):

You may convert your SVN repository using [SubGit](http://subgit.com) project. It will convert branches to refs/heads/*, tags to refs/tags/*; so that you'll eventually get an usual Git repository that you can push to GitHub as any other Git repository.
And by the way after installation of SubGit into your SVN repository, your SVN repository will be automatically in sync with your Git repository (until you run "subgit uninstall" on it), so no effort is required for additional synchronization.